# How can I write the data received after the loop to a json file?

Tags: json, bash, jq

I want to make a script that will generate a list of certificates that will expire in a month and write it in json format to a file.

Making a loop and getting the list as regular strings is not a problem. I can’t yet understand how to format the resulting list in json form. So that it would be like this:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "{expiration_date}": "test1_expiration_date_value",
      "{serial_number}": "test1_expiration_date_value"
    },
    {
      "{expiration_date}": "test2_expiration_date_value",
      "{serial_number}": "test2_expiration_date_value"
    },
    {
      "{expiration_date}": "testN_expiration_date_value",
      "{serial_number}": "testN_expiration_date_value"
    }
  ]
}
```

I make a curl request to get a list of certificates
`curl --header "..." --request LIST https://some_uri | jq -r '.data.keys' | grep '\w' | tr -d '""',','`
In response I receive:

```
[
  "test1",
  "test2",
  "testN"
]
```

Then you can request additional fields for each of the lists
`curl -s --header "..." --request GET https://some_uri/test1 | jq -r '.data.data'`
In response I receive:

```
{
  "expiration_date": "2023-10-11 11:27:10",
  "serial_number": "18:df:b4:a8:34:25:b1:43:c9:a3:6d:83:59:34:53:ab:2c:5e:c2:7a"
}
```

I tried different designs, but have not won yet. The last option, without any conditions for now:

```
#!/bin/bash

date=$(date -d "+1 month")

cert_list=$(curl -s --header "..." --request LIST https://some_uri | jq -r '.data.keys' | grep '\w' | tr -d '""',',')

list=()
for i in $cert_list
do
  cert_data=$(curl -s --header "..." --request GET https://some_uri/$i | jq -r '.data.data | "\(.expiration_date) \(.serial_number)"')
  list+="$cert_data"$'\n'
done

list_json="$(printf '%s\n' "${list}")"
json="$(jq -Rn '{data: [inputs]}' <<< "$list")"

printf '%s\n' "$json"
```

Comment: What's the output of `curl --header "..." --request LIST https://some_uri` ? It looks like it's JSON already so you should only need to use jq

Comment: there is only a general list of entries
{"request_id":"90780c5d-4b3b-1e94-8368-5a7a3bb10b04","lease_id":"","renewable":false,"lease_duration":0,"data":{"keys":["test1","test2"]},"wrap_info":null,"warnings":null,"auth":null}

Comment: to request detailed data you need to curl before each entry, as I wrote above

Comment: Can I ask why you are using bash for this? There comes a point I find where the manipulations I am doing are more succinctly written with another language.

Comment: python or go is also possible, but I’m less comfortable with them than with bash)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `curl … https://some_uri | jq '.data.keys'` outputs a JSON array of strings like `["test1", "test2", "testN"]`, and `curl … https://some_uri/test1 | jq '.data.data'` outputs a JSON object like `{"expiration_date": "…", "serial_number": "…"}`, then the following might solve your task.

It fetches the results from the first URI, and outputs a NUL-delimited list of strings that were contained in the array under `.data.keys`. Shell's `while` then iterates over that list using `read -d ''` to segment along the NUL characters, and in each step it fetches the results from the other URI (with the current list item appended), and extracts the object under `.data.data`, but leaves it JSON-encoded. A final call to jq then collects all of them in an array using the `-s` flag, and wraps it into an object with field name `data`.

```
#!/bin/bash

curl … "https://some_uri" | jq --raw-output0 '.data.keys[]' |
while read -r -d '' key; do
  curl … "https://some_uri/${key}" | jq '.data.data'
done | jq -s '{data: .}'
```

Comment: Thank you. This looks like what is needed, the only thing or a problem with the syntax or something else, but it returns an empty result. Separately, everything works as it should, but in the while loop, it doesn’t work. I haven't found the reason yet.

Comment: @ElRamos Which version of jq are you using? If it's not 1.7, you won't have `--raw-output0` (with the `0` at the end). In this case, try replacing the entire command with `jq -j '.data.keys[], "\u0000"'`.

Comment: version 1.6. I tried a new option, it started adding “null”
{
  "data": [
    null
  ]
}

Comment: Separately, curl requests always return what I wrote above in the example

Comment: It was necessary to do it through '+', and everything works. 
jq -j '.data.keys[]+"\u0000"'
Thank you.

Comment: @ElRamos My bad, I wanted to write `jq -j '.data.keys[] | ., "\u0000"'` (missed putting `| .` before the comma), but using `+` is also a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

An ugly way would be to directly concatenate the second request responses in a string, and then manipulate this string to separate objects with comma and add opening and closing square brackets:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

date=$(date -d "+1 month")

cert_list=$(curl -s --header "..." --request LIST https://some_uri | jq -r '.data.keys' | grep '\w' | tr -d '""',',')

list=""
for i in $cert_list
do
  cert_data=$(curl -s --header "..." --request GET https://some_uri/$i | jq -r '.data.data | "\(.expiration_date) \(.serial_number)"')
  list+="$cert_data"$'\n'
done

json="$(echo "[" $(echo "$list" | sed 's/}{/},{/g') "]")"
```